# Java Method Error | Answer Included

Tags: java

Please help me restore my sanity! Take a look at the program below, please. This program runs correctly when I call it. The intended result that I'm looking for is:

```
triangle 0, area = 4.0
triangle 1, area = 10.0
triangle 2, area = 18.0
triangle 3, area = 28.0
```

Now the part that I am stuck in is during the `while` loop when `t[x].setArea()` gets call. I can't get over the way the method is currently written. **For some reason I think it should be written like this:**

```
void setArea() {      
    t[x].area = (t[x].height * t[x].length)/2;
  }
```

**Instead of how is currently written:**

```
 void setArea() {
    area = (height * length)/2;
```

**Because how those it know that you are referring to that particular t[x] without actually calling it directly like this**

```
t[x].area  t[x].height  t[x].length
```

Please let me know what you think. Is very confusing.

```
  class Triangle {
  double area;
  int height;
  int length;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    Triangle [] ta = new Triangle[4];

    while (x < 4) {
      ta[x] = new Triangle();
      ta[x].height = (x + 1) *2;
      ta[x].length = x + 4;
      ta[x].setArea();

      System.out.print("triangle "+x+", area");
      System.out.println(" = "+ta[x].area);
      x = x + 1;
    }
    int y = x;
    x = 27;
    Triangle t5 = ta[2];
    ta[2].area = 343;
    System.out.print("y = " + y);
    System.out.println(", t5 area = "+ t5.area);
  }

  void setArea() {
    area = (height * length)/2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you would move your main method in another class: setArea() is a method af a Triangle object. It allways belongs to a specific Triangle and has no idea that the array of triangles in your main method even exists.

Comment: You should not store the area. You should store height and length and calculate the area in a method getArea()

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I'm currently learning from  "Head First Java" and they have it this way. Maybe when I get deeper in the book it will move it out to its own class. I was wondering if by calling the method: ta[x].setArea() . Those the inside of the method assume to use ta[x].area ...ta[x].length internally? Thanks man!

Comment: @jens Right I shouldn't store the Area...But my question is when the Area is been calculate how those it know which height and length to use if it doesn't have the ta[x].length and ta[x].width internally. Those the inside of the method assume to use ta[x].area ...ta[x].length internally, since we have already call it using ta[x].setArea()?   -Thank you

Comment: @rnd809 ta[x].setArea() calls the setArea() method of ta[x]. As i already said that triangle itself doesn't know or needs to know that it is an array. But it of course knows about its own properties (height, length). In laymen terms what you are doing is telling the Triangle at ta[x]: "Hey you triangle, set your area!" to which the triangle itself respons with "okay, i just multiply my height with length and save that in area".

Comment: @md809 why you calculate it you should only use the instance variable not the Array.

Comment: Note that `(height * length)/2` is an `int`, so the result will be truncated if `height * length` is odd.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS In laymen's terms what you are doing is telling the Triangle at ta[x]: "Hey you triangle, set your area!"....

I got that part....But now when the triangle sets the area and needs to get the length and height shouldn't it do it by calling itself with a (dot)length and (dot)width?

Comment: @rnd809 It looks like you need to learn a bit about the difference between static and non-static (especially understand the implicit `this` parameter of non-static method) and what are the difference between a class and an instance of the class.

Comment: "shouldn't it do it by calling itself with a (dot)length and (dot)width" <- referencing itself in java is done with the keyword `this`. But this keyword (pun intended) can be obmitted. So you could also write the setArea method as `this.area = (this.height * this.length)/2;`.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS You are amazing, thank you! I will talk to God to please not send any Spiders your way :) Thank you!

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do will be much more clearer if you use two classes:

The triangle object:

```
public class Triangle {
    int height;
    int length;
    double area;

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }




    void setArea() {
        area = (height * length) / 2;
    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        Triangle[] ta = new Triangle[4];

        while (x < 4) {
            ta[x] = new Triangle();
            ta[x].height = (x + 1) * 2;
            ta[x].length = x + 4;
            ta[x].setArea();

            System.out.print("triangle " + x + ", area");
            System.out.println(" = " + ta[x].area);
            x = x + 1;
        }
        int y = x;
        x = 27;
        Triangle t5 = ta[2];
        ta[2].area = 343;
        System.out.print("y = " + y);
        System.out.println(", t5 area = " + t5.area);
    }
}
```

Now you see that you not have Access to the Array anymore.

But i would suggest to not store the area.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason, the book that I'm using has it written this way. But I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: @rnd809 If my answer elps you, feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0):

The method `setArea()` is defined inside the `Triangle`-class, which means that all instances of `Triangle` has its own version of this method, refering to its own field variables (i.e. `area`, `height` and `length`).

Therefore, when you call `ta[x].setArea();`, the `setArea` method will implicitly know that the variables refer to those of `ta[x]`.

Comment: Thank you! So much for another perspective!

Answer (score -1):

In java , whenever a method of a class is called a this pointer is passed. So you need not to do : 
 **t[x].area = (t[x].height * t[x].length)/2**

Rather what is already written i.e.
 **area = (height * length)/2**

works fine and because of the this pointer being passed behind the scenes , the code works and updates exactly the instance for which it is desired.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you!

Comment: I did not vote you down... Let me vote it up. Thank you so much. Actually, I just try to vote up and is saying that I don't have enough Votes to vote. So, I didn't vote you down.

Comment: No problem :) .